# Trouble converting PUT from command line to php

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform, put

I am having trouble converting a PUT curl command into php. I just figured out how to convert a POST method into PHP but I am having a difficult time with using PUT to update my database on Parse.com.

This is my curl statement:

```
  curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: app id" \  
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: rest api"   
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"   
  -d '{"site_status":"statusValue"}'   
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass/objectId
```

(SOLVED): The information is being updated to Parse!!!

```
<?php 

 $ch = curl_init('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClientCompanyInfo/objectID');

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
      array('X-Parse-Application-Id:app_id',
      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key:rest_api_id',
      'Content-Type: application/json'));

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"site_status\":\"siteValueStatus\"}");

 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$headers = array(
  'X-Parse-Application-Id: app_id',
  'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: rest_key',
  'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClass/objectId';
$changes = array(
  'site_status' => 'statusValue'
);
$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($changes));
$response = curl_exec($rest);
curl_close($rest);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Also... keep an eye out in the next few weeks, for some Parse PHP news.

Comment: I added the code but nothing changed in my database. I added curl_exec($rest); to get rid of an error I was having. What do you think is my problem? I think my problem is the **'site_status' => 'statusValue'** line. What does the => syntax mean?

Comment: that syntax is how you build an associative array in PHP.  You need to log out the results to see what the response is..

Comment: I added a echo curl_exec($rest) and I got the error {"error":"unauthorized"}.

Comment: sure you have the right app id and rest api key in there?.. the error says otherwise.

Comment: I posted my updated code, I am using the correct Application ID and REST API Key from my settings page. Did I incorrectly write my $changes variable?

Comment: Ok lets try one quick change... http_build_query($changes)

Comment: updated the code to change how the headers array is set.. try that.

Comment: Thank you for trying so hard to help me. I am really frustrated from my error. I now get the error **string(24) "{"error":"unauthorized"}"** from my var_dump. Does that mean that my $changes is having problems?

Comment: Really not sure what's going on there...  can you send me an email to fjm@fb.com please?

Comment: I just shot you an email. Thank you again.